# How to restrict access to a non-const public member m of a class A to be const to a another class B, containing A as a non-const member?

Tags: c++, software-design, const-correctness

aI find this question to be interesting for other people, too. So I choose this one to finally ask my first question on Stack Overflow. A minimal description of the situation is the following:

```
class A {
public:
    Type_m_first m_first;
    Type_m_second m_second;
}

class B { // shoud be const on a.m_first
private:
    A& a; 
public:
    B(A& a_) : a(a_) {};
}
```

**EDIT:** *Setting the members of `A` to be `private` and using getters and setters is not a solution to my problem. However, I hope for a solution as easy as this, because I well might miss something easy, due to my lack of experience in programming.*

Now, I need any yet-to-be-implemented method of `B` to have only `const` access to `A.m_first` while having non-`const` access to `A.m_second`, and similarly, I need any other code using something of type `B` having the same access restrictions, when accessing `B.a`. Of course, this is impossible (at least from my humble point of view).

Nevertheless, my question is:

**How is it possible to enforce on the class `B` such a `const`-restriction of the access to a non-`const` member variable?**

**EDIT** *With private `m_first` and `m_second` and a getters and setters for `m_first` and `m_second` the situation would be the same. Then the questions is: How to restrict the access of `B` to the `const` getter of `m_first`, and deny `B` the access to the setter of `m_first`, while at the same time allow `B` to use the setter of `m_second`?*

---

The above is the question. However, without the following context this question might be incomplete as it illustrates the significance of the question. The actual situation I am facing is the following:

```
class A {
public:
    Type_m_first m_first;
    Type_m_second m_second;
public:
    // A lot of code.
private:
    // A lot of code.
}

class B { // shoud be const on a.m_first
private:
    A& a;
public:
    B(A& a_) : a(a_) {};
private: 
    // A lot of code, that I am supposed to move from somewhere else to here
    // or write myself.
public: 
    // A lot of code, that I am supposed to move from somewhere else to here
    // or write myself.
}

class C { // shoud be const on a.m_second
private:
    A& a;
public:
    C(A& a_) : a(a_) {};
private: 
    // A lot of code, that I am supposed to move from somewhere else to here
    // or write myself.
public: 
    // A lot of code, that I am supposed to move from somewhere else to here
    // or write myself.
}

/* 
 * A lot of other Code that is supposed to work with A, B and C. The following three
 * functions serve as an example. As you see, everything is manipulating essentially 
 * the same data from a.
 */ 

 void f(A& a, /* other args */ ) { /* ... */ }; 
 void g(B& b, /* other args */ ) { /* ... */ }; // shoud be const on b.a.m_first by design
 int h(C& c, /* other args */ ) { /* ... */ };  // shoud be const on c.a.m_second by design
 
 int main() {
     A a; 
     B b = B(a);
     C c = C(a);

     f(a, /* other args */ );
     g(b, /* other args */ );
     return h(c, /* other args */ );
 }
```

Again, I need any yet-to-be-implemented method of `B` to have only `const` access to `A.m_first` while having non-`const` access to `A.m_second`. However, for the class `C` I need this to be exactly the other way round: I need any yet-to-be-implemented method of `C` to have only `const` access to `A.m_second` while having non-`const` access to `A.m_first`. Similarily, any Code using something of type `B` and `C` should have corresponding access-restrictions.

Again, of course, the question arises: Why do I need this? And the answer is, that the logical structure of the algorithm would be enforced by such a design. Making everything public is only in so far a concern, as neglecting the logical structure by accident leads to hard to find bugs in the code and due to the complexity of the code it is hard to keep track of such restrictions which are not enforced by design.

The best solution I had come up with - but did not yet implement -, is copying the code to two wrapper classes:

```
class A_first {
public:
    const Type_m_first& m_first;
    Type_m_second& m_second;
    A_first(A&) ; m_first(const A.m_first), m_second(A.m_second) {};
public:
    // Same code as before.
protected:
    // Same code as before.
private:
    // Same code as before.
}

class A_second {
public:
    Type_m_first& m_first;
    const Type_m_second& m_second;
    A_first(A&) ; m_first(A.m_first), m_second(const A.m_second) {};
public:
    // Same code as before.
protected:
    // Same code as before.
private:
    // Same code as before.
}
```

This is not desirabe, because the code changes a lot over time, and keeping track of the changes in three classes is error-prone. My question is, what to do in such a situation?

Comment: It's hard to give advice without knowing much about the code we don't see. But the answer of @HAL9000 already points the direction: if a data member is not to be manipulated outside a class (i.e. the default) it should be private and there should be getter / setter methods. Additionally, the code manipulating data members of, e.g., A should preferably live inside A as well; same holds for B and C. So maybe your functions  f, g, h might end up being methods of A, B and C.

Comment: @kaba Thank you very much, I edited the question and made it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm highly in doubt whether this is worth the effort, but this might suit your needs:

Instead of passing `B` and `C` a reference to `A` (which would grant them unlimited access to `A`, which is your whole problem if I understand correctly), only pass them the accessors to the two members. This could look like so:

```
class B {
private:
    std::function<Type_m_first const&()> getConstFirst;
    std::function<Type_m_second&()> getNonConstSecond;
public:
    B(std::function<Type_m_first const&()> f1, std::function<Type_m_second&()> f2)
        : getConstFirst(std::move(f1)), getNonConstSecond(std::move(f2)) {};

    void someMethod() {
        getConstFirst() = abc; // this won't compile
        getNonConstSecond() = xyz; // this will
    }
}
```

Analogous implementation for `C`.

Then, pass functions to the c'tors of `B` and `C` using lambdas that capture the instance of `A` by reference:

```
A a; 
B b = B(
    [&a]() -> auto const& { return a.m_first; },
    [&a]() -> auto& { return a.m_second; }
    );
C c = C(
    [&a]() -> auto& { return a.m_first; },
    [&a]() -> auto const& { return a.m_second; }
    );
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is an answer to my question. This is more complicated than I hoped for, hence I did not yet accept it as an answer. If I will not find a different solution myself, or get a better answer in a while, I will accept this answer.

Comment: (I am not sure if this is according to netiquette on stackoverflow. If not, I am happy to do differently. If someone is nice enough to point that out to me.)

Comment: Follow-up question: Why is the std::move() necessary?

Comment: @Kokoro not accepting it in order to wait for something better is totally fine :) `std::move` is not necessary. It just avoids a copy. You can leave it out if you don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have to confess, I just skimmed reading you question, so I might have missed some details. But wouldn't a getter that returns a `const` reference be what you need?

```
class A {
private:
    Type_m_first m_first;
public:
    const Type_m_first & get_m_first() const { return m_first; }

    Type_m_second m_second;
}
```

Here only members of `A` might modify `m_first` directly. Everybody else must use the the `const` reference obtained by `get_m_first`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I edited the question and made it more clear.

Comment: @HAL9000 Now that the m_first is private so you'll be needing a setter for it. How will you implement it?

Comment: If the requirement is to have only const access to `m_first` then why would you need a setter? Const means non modifiable...